# Exclude children based on content in XML with PHP (simplexml)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Another question about PHP and XML...

Is it posible to exclude children based on there childrens content.

See the example below:
If "title" contains the word "XTRA:" I don't want this "movie" to be listed.

**This is my PHP code:**

```
<? $xml = simplexml_load_file("movies.xml");
foreach ($xml->movie as $movie){ ?>

<h2><? echo $movie->title ?></h2>
<p>Year: <? echo $movie->year ?></p>

<? } ?>
```

**This is mys XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <title>Little Fockers</title>
    <year>2010</year>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Little Fockers XTRA: teaser 3</title>
    <year>2010</year>
</movie>
</movies>
```

**The outcome of the code above is:**

```
<h2>Little Fockers</h2>
<p>Year: 2010</p>

<h2>Little Fockers XTRA: teaser 3</h2>
<p>Year: 2010</p>
```

**I want it to be only:**

```
<h2>Little Fockers</h2>
<p>Year: 2010</p>
```

Comment: Hi dqhendricks and prodigitalson,

I am alsways answering the answers I get. I am very thankful for your help. I hade my Cookoies disabled when I asked the other question. Tried to answer but couldn't... Was hoping the same guys would answer this question to so I could thank you all (this is a nother question)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to filter nodes. The first is with [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) (the version supported by libxml/SimpleXML)

```
$movies = simplexml_load_file("movies.xml");

foreach ($movies->xpath('movie[not(contains(title, "XTRA:"))]') as $movie)
{
    echo '<h2>', $movie->title, '</h2>';
}
```

Here, we use the [contains function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains), which is XPath's equivalent to [PHP's strpos()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Unfortunately, XPath 1.0 only has a few string functions and all of them are case sensitive. So while XPath is very adapted to handle complex hierarchy, it's not so good at dealing with string. In that case, you can fallback to a PHP solution such as:

```
$movies = simplexml_load_file("movies.xml");

foreach ($movies->movie as $movie)
{
    if (stripos($movie->title, 'XTRA:') !== false)
    {
        // skip to next iteration
        continue;
    }

    echo '<h2>', $movie->title, '</h2>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for a great answer! Both examples works great.

This is very helpful when trying to learn PHP & XML.

Thanks a lot!